# Secured And Unsecured Pages in Asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, security, c#-4.0

I am developing a Web Applilcation in Asp.net 4.0 , wherein i have two types of Pages "Secured" and "Unsecured".

To access Secure Pages, the user must successfully Login.

This can be acheived in two ways:

1st Approach : Location Tag in web.config file.

2nd Approach : Make 2 virtual directories for Secured and Unsecured.

Please suggest the better approach and also suggest ,if any other better option available.

Thanks In Advance.....

Answer (score 2):

The "Location Tag" is the better, because even if you use virtual directories, you also need to use a "Location Tag" again, a redirect from unsecure to secure - so to be sure for each virtual directory, that is the same as any directory.

This is a very good project that can make this for you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7206/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically-Ver

the automatically switch from http to https base on rules.

Comment: shall i use the asp.net membership tables and asp.net configuration tool or write my own tables and custom code. Please advice.....

Comment: @poonammarda No, I have give you a link that is code that made the switch from http to https automatically. The rules are written on web.config. Download it, work with it and you understand what is do